# Is the "New Type Idiom/Pattern" the same as a struct with one field?

Tags: rust

Given a "New Type"

```
struct MyState(bool);
```

and a "normal" struct

```
struct MyState
{
    value: bool,
}
```

Are these two structs the same, except for naming self.0 and self.value?

Are they both zero-cost abstractions?

Answer (score 3):

> Are these two structs the same, except of naming self.0 and self.value ?

Yes

> Are they both zero-cost abstractions ?

Yes

[Tuple structs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.struct.html) in general are just structs whose fields don’t have names.